# module not loaded yet for context

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Quick question... I have a define for requirejs setup like so...  it works about 8-10% of the time.  It seems that a resource sometime isn't loaded in time.  Can I wrap the above var require list in a way that ensures the code below it will run correctly?  The error I get when it doesn't work is this:

**Uncaught Error: Module name "views/association/Associations" has not been loaded yet for context: _**

```
define(function( require ){
  // requirejs - too many includes to pass in the array
  var $ = require('jquery'),
      _ = require('underscore'),
      Backbone = require('backbone'),
      namespace = require('namespace'),
      // models
      CustomerModel = require('models/customer/customer'),
      // collections
      // views
      BaseView = require('views/baseView'),
      Auth = require('views/auth/Auth'),
      SideNav = require('views/sidenav/SideNav'),
      CustomersView = require('views/customer/Customers'),
      AssociationsView = require('views/association/Associations'),
      //CustomerListCpeView = require('views/customer/CustomerListCpe'),
      //CustomerAddCpeView = require('views/customer/CustomerAddCpe'),
      // templates
      CustomerDetailTemplate = require('text!templates/customer/customerDetail.html');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even with the "traditional" or non-sugar method (http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar), this error persisted. It turned out that there was a circular import that I accidentally introduced into the codebase during a refactor.  Removing that circular import removed this error.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    // ...
    'views/association/Associations'
    // ...
], function($, _, Backbone, /* ..., */ AssociationsView) {

    // ...
});
```

Comment: I don't like that convention.  It's a pain in the butt when you have a lot of defines/requires. I use the alternate loading method, http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar